# Axios AbortController not working for me in reactjs

Tags: node.js, reactjs, react-hooks, axios

I tried loading a page and immediately returns to the previous page. I expect it to abort but the api calls still pull through and fetch data successfully when I checked the network tab. Here is my code:

```
      useEffect(() => {
      const controller = new AbortController();
      
      const getPost = async () => {
       try{
          setIsLoading(true)
        const response = await axios.get(`${BASE_URL}/posts/${path}`, {signal: 
        controller.signal})
       
        setUsername(response.data.username)
        
        setIsLoading(false)
        
       }catch(err){
     
            if(err.response.data == 'ERR_ABORTED 400'){
                return console.log('request canceled')
            }
          setIsLoading(false)
        if(err.response.data === 'no post found'){
            return setgeneralFetchError(true)
        }
        
       }
       
        return ()=>{
    controller.abort()
  }
   };

   
  getPost()
   
 
}, [path]);
```

It is my first time of trying to do this. probably I am not doing it properly.

Comment: Have you confirmed the returned function is being called? I would add some console logging to the method before the call to `controller.abort()`

Comment: It is not called. That is the issue. The return function is not called and I dont know why.

Comment: You need to have your return statement after `getPost()` instead of inside the getPost function

Comment: Did that already, not working

Comment: I am also having a problem with this, but I am using Vue3

Answer (score -1):

try to remove the await and check

```
    useEffect(() => {
  const controller = new AbortController();
  const getPost = async () => {
    try {
      setIsLoading(true)
      const response = axios.get(`${BASE_URL}/posts/${path}`, { signal: controller.signal })
      setUsername(response.data.username)
      setIsLoading(false)
    } catch (err) {
      if (err.response.data == 'ERR_ABORTED 400') console.log('request canceled')
      setIsLoading(false)
      if (err.response.data === 'no post found') setgeneralFetchError(true)
    }
  };
  getPost()
  return () => controller.abort()
}, [path]);
```